# webkit transform not work in safari

Tags: animation, transform

Webkit animation works fine in firefox, chrome, IE and opera but not correctly in safari. webkit animation not work fine in safari. why?

```
.t-ads {
margin: 10px auto;
text-align:center;
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
background: #41515a;
border-radius: 10px;
font-size:10px;color:#FFFFFF;
transition-property: width, height, transform, background,color, font-size, opacity;
transition-duration: 1s, 1s, 1s, 1s, 1s, 1s,1s;
}
.t-ads:hover {
margin: 10px auto;
text-align:center;
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
background: #3399FF;
font-size:20px;
color:#000000;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `-webkit-transform` to the `transition` property list:

```
.t-ads {
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #41515a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;

    -webkit-transition-property: width, height, -webkit-transform, background, color, font-size, opacity;
    transition-property: width, height, -webkit-transform, transform, background, color, font-size, opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Only one value needed if all are the same */
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.t-ads:hover {
    background: #3399FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

As you seem to want to animate all the properties you change, you could simply specify `all` for the `transition` and `-webkit-transition` properties. For further brevity, use the shorthand syntax to specify all the transition properties at once:

```
.t-ads {
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #41515a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -transition: all 1s;
}
```

Your original code worked in Firefox and Chrome because they support the unprefixed `transform` property. Incidentally, you don't need to redefine property values in the `:hover` state which don't change (you'll notice I've removed `margin`, `text-align`, `width` and `height` from the `:hover` block).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmzm96q5/4/)

Comment: I add `-webkit-transform` to the `transition` property list, but not work again!

Comment: Aah, you'll probably need to use -webkit-transition. I'll update my answer. Edit: updated answer - let me know if that works for you.